# NBA Draft Lottery remove array item after it is revealed upon button click

Tags: javascript, arrays, button, generator

https://jsfiddle.net/7jux5rLx/3/?

full code above

I'm trying to make a random nba draft lottery for 8 teams (using array with 8 images) that reveals the image of the team with the 8th pick on button click and then removes it from the array list leaving only the 7 remaining teams and so on. **I dont want to remove the image**, just the item as an option from the array when I click the following 7 buttons. So currently I am trying to use 8 list images in the array, and 8 buttons all numbered from 1-8. I want it similar to nba's draft lottery so if anyone has a code with a formula for the percentages it would be great.

the odds for each team would be this chances for 1st pick = 25%, 2nd pick 16.4%, 3rd pick 16.4%, 4th pick 16.3%, 5th pick 9.4%, 6th pick 6.6%, 7th pick 4.4%, 8th pick 2.7%,
here is what I have now. I can't seem to even get the button to reveal a random team. This is for a fantasy league not a professional site or anything.

```
function teams() {
  var aTeams = [];
  aTeams[0] = "<img src='http://i.imgur.com/KowPAjR.png' height='100' width='100' alt='cavs'>";

  aTeams[1] = "<img src='http://i.imgur.com/KowPAjR.png' height='100' width='100' alt='suns'>";

  aTeams[2] = "<img src='http://i.imgur.com/KowPAjR.png' height='100' width='100' alt='rockets'>";

  aTeams[3] = "<img src='http://i.imgur.com/KowPAjR.png' height='100' width='100' alt='nuggets'>";

  aTeams[4] = "<img src='http://i.imgur.com/KowPAjR.png' height='100' width='100' alt='celtics'>";

  aTeams[5] = "<img src='http://i.imgur.com/KowPAjR.png' height='100' width='100' alt='raptors'>";

  aTeams[6] = "<img src='http://i.imgur.com/KowPAjR.png' height='100' width='100' alt='thunder'>";

  aTeams[7] = "<img src='http://i.imgur.com/KowPAjR.png' height='100' width='100' alt='warriors'>";
  var rdmTeams = Math.floor(Math.random() * aTeams.length);
  document.getElementById("table").value = aTeams[rdmTeams];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/7jux5rLx/4/

This is by no means perfect. It needs some formatting of the code, but it is what you asked for I believe. There is html you need on the fiddle.

```
/*
* Create a listener for a button click
*/
var table = document.getElementById("table");
table.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    if (event.target.nodeName == "BUTTON") {
        // Get the div corresponding to the button clicked
        var thisPickDiv = document.getElementById(event.target.id.replace("Btn", "Div"));
        var rdmNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * aTeams.length);
        thisPickDiv.innerHTML = aTeams[rdmNum];
        aTeams.splice(rdmNum, 1);
    }
});
```

The image stays on the page. I hope that is what you meant by not removing the image. If not this can easily be done by having two arrays (one for teams and the other for the img sources) but I do not know what benefit that would afford you.

Comment: This is great man. Thank you so much. How about an algorithm for generating weighted random numbers so that say the cavs team gets a 25% chance at getting the number one pick instead of using the Math.random() function to randomize all teams. would I just need to create 8 separate functions for each of the teams in the array or what. If I knew the correct formula for just one of the functions the other 7 would simple be copy pasting the function and adjusting it to the correct odds. also any way I could have the contents of each button click emailed to my league after its clicked?

Comment: I would look into Google's Gmail API to send the email. That's much easier than dealing with all the mail transfer protocols. When I get time tonight I will work on the weighted random numbers. Can you send me a link in the meantime how the NBA weighs the picks?

Comment: hey thank you for your reply. I found a way to do weighted random numbers using the ES5 Array method reduce. I do still need to figure out how to send the results from the table via email on button click after I reveal the #1 Pick last.